# java swing graphics2d drawstring not working

Tags: java, swing

```
BufferedImage image=new BufferedImage(32,32,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2=image.createGraphics();
        g2.setBackground(Color.white);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.drawString("A",0,0);
        ImageIO.write(image,"PNG",new File("1.png"));
```

It just giving me an empty white image. Why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
    g2.drawString("A", 0, 16);
```

(0,0) is the upper left corner and the drawString coordinates are for the lower left point where you want to draw